# Canvas drawImage in WebView not working with image reused

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, android-webview

I'm trying to show the photo and rotate it for 90 degrees on the Android phone after each click. It works fine with smaller images, but for the photos of 8 megapixels after clicking for a while (e.g. about 10 times) ctx.drawImage stops drawing anything. It looks like some memory leak in Android WebView, cuz' the Chrome on my phone shows the large images fine.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ROTATING_image.html");
```

The html code is such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(undefined) {
        var $ = function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        };
        var draw = function(degree) {
            var ctx = $('canvas').getContext('2d');

            var cw = img.width, ch = img.height, cx = 0, cy = 0;
            switch (degree) {
            case 90:
                cw = img.height;
                ch = img.width;
                cy = img.height * (-1);
                break;
            case 180:
                cx = img.width * (-1);
                cy = img.height * (-1);
                break;
            case 270:
                cw = img.height;
                ch = img.width;
                cx = img.width * (-1);
                break;
            }

            $('canvas').height = ch;
            $('canvas').width = cw;
            degree && ctx.rotate(degree * Math.PI / 180);
            ctx.drawImage(img,cx,cy);
        };
        var img = new Image;
            //Works fine with such small image, but not with the 8 megapixel one
        img.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wNKEHHjRDlc/T665lI3U5RI/AAAAAAAAX_4/95A2vEhdx_c/s720/IMG_1592.JPG';
        img.onload = function() {
            draw()
        };
        var curDegree = 0;
        $('canvas').onclick = function(e) {
            curDegree=curDegree+90;
            if(curDegree==360)
                {curDegree=0;}
            draw(curDegree);
        };
    })();
</script>
</html>
```